# jQuery - get first paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<div class="side-box">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
    <p>
        This is paragraph 1<br><br>
        This is paragraph 1<br><br>
        This is paragraph 3<br><br>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a jQuery function that will display anything up to the first paragraph and then display the rest when a 'read more' link is clicked.

The content is generated by a WYSIWYG editor, otherwise i'm sure I would be able to create this function myself.

Comment: What's the difference between content generated by an editor and fixed content? Assuming it is fixed how would you create the function you are talking about?

Comment: Hey, The content generated by the editor uses break tags rather than p tags.

Comment: Your HTML is badly formatted. You never close the <p>. Also, perhaps you might want to clarify whether you are talking about a paragraph of text or actually the <p> tag.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.side-box > p').not(':first-child').hide();
```

But you dont have more than 1 paragraph in your code, do you mean after first break(br)?

---

You can remove everything after first BR by using:

```
var str = $('.side-box p').html();
var substr = str.split('<br>');
$('.side-box p').html(substr[0]);
```

It searches the P, and splits it by the BR tags.

Then we take the first split and replace the p content with it :)

Comment: hi ya, Yeah, The editor is not generating p tags, just double break tags

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I just noticed the paragraphs aren't *actually* paragraphs in the sense of `p` tags (which define a paragraph in mark-up) - though what you ask for will still be possible, it might be a better consideration to fix the way content is being paragraphed in your editor.

---

The following ought to do the tick...

```
var paragraph = $("p:eq(0)").html();
```

Though you might want to play with `html()`, `text()` and `val()` calls, I never get the correct one first time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "show link" for all paragraphs and hide the paragraph itself:

```
var paragraphs = $(".side-box > p");
paragraphs.before(function () {
    return $("<a>Read more</a>").click(function () {
        // hide the "Read more" link. Alternatively, use .remove() to remove the link
        $(this).hide();
        // this link was inserted before the paragraph, so displaying the next element
        // (= paragraph)
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
// hide the paragraphs which are now preceded by a "Read more" link
paragraphs.hide();
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VU28t/)

Comment: This is almost perfect. Can we get it to display the first paragraph as well before the 'read more' link?

Answer (score 0):

Example [working with your current HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwick/67DTf/).

```
$('.side-box p').first().each(function(i,e){
    htmlchunks = $(this).html().split('<br><br>');
    first_part = htmlchunks.shift();
    secondpart = $('<div class="hidden"/>').hide().html(htmlchunks.join('<br><br>'));
    $(this).html(first_part + '<a class="readmore">read more</a>').append(secondpart);
});

$('.readmore').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').show();
    $(this).detach();
});
```

Yikes, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS ( IE >= 9, because of the first-of-type ) - for reference check support here - [Can I Use first-of-type](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type)

```
.side-box p:first-of-type ~ * {
    display:none;
}
```

The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent. ( IE 7+ )

[General sibling selectors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)